# How to import a module without sub-imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I'm building a module, but I'm having some hard times understanding which is the best-practice to avoid workspace pollution.

## Example code

My module is:

```
aModule\
    __init__.py
    aSubModule.py
    someFunctions.py
```

The contents of the files are:

**init**.py

```
from .someFunctions import function1, function2
from aModule import aSubModule
```

someFunctions.py

```
from numpy import exp,log,sqrt

def function1():
    print('function1: Hello World!')
    
def function2():
    print('function2: Hello ' + aUtilityFunction())
    
def aUtilityFunction(): #This should not be imported
    return 'World!'
```

aSubModule.py

```
from numpy import exp,log,sqrt

def function3():
    print('I am function 3')
    
def function4():
    print('I am function 4')
```

## The problem

When doing

```
import aModule
```

I would like to be able to access

```
aModule.function1()
aModule.function2()
aModule.aSubModule.function3()
aModule.aSubModule.function4()
```

However I have also the following unwanted behaviour:

### Problem 1

The file *someFunctions.py* is imported as a submodule. In other words, I can access function1 both from aModule.function1 and from aModule.someFunctions.function1 . This is, in my opinion, messy.
The only solution I found to this is to rename the file _someFunctions.py . The leading underscore is now telling Python not to import it. This looks fine, but I'm not sure if this is considered good practice.

### Problem 2

The functions exp, log and sqrt are imported under aModule.aSubModule. I would like to access the functions inside *aSubModule* doing

```
aModule.aSubModule.function3()
```

but I would like to avoid having exp, log and sqrt inside aModule.aSubModule

This is because inside the "real" sub module i'm working to, I have just 3-4 functions that are relevant to the user, but more than 10-15 imports. Therefore when I try to tab-complete

```
aModule.aSubModule.<tab>
```

about 20 entries pop-up, of which just 3-4 are relevant.

Comment: You can prefix a function with a underscore (`_`) to hide it from help and autocompletion. Isn't it enough?

Comment: so I should import numpy as _np, pandas as _pd and name my files _someFunction ?

I think this could work, but I tried to open some modules made by others to see how they did it and never saw this technique. Is this good-practice?

Comment: Unsure of it, but I think that what you want is the `from module import *` syntax that imports only the symbols explicitely listed in the `__all__` special variable of the module. More detail in [official doc.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package)

Comment: Unfortunately the `__all__` special variable does not affect the behaviours described in my post. I don't want to use the `import *` syntax, but just avoid importing sub modules when importing the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a nice way, but hacks are possible. The trick is that any identifier starting with an underscore will not be used by the help system not for *tab* autocompletion, even if it is a module identifier. So to avoid automatic access to unnecessary identifier, you can have packages containing *private* modules

```
aModule\
    __init__.py
    _someFunctions.py
    aSubModule\
        __init__.py
        _aSubModule.py
```

Content of `aModule __init__.py`:

```
from ._subFunctions import f1, f2
from . import aSubModule
```

Content of `aSubModule __init__.py`:

```
from ._aSubModule import f3, f4
```

I must admit it is rather hacky and not very Pythonic. Maybe a custom importer would lead to cleaner code, but I could not find my way through the `importlib` module.

My conclusion is that the Pythonic way is probably not to try to hide names imported through a module, but just import in the current namespace the names you need.